# What changes do I need to make in the following program?

Tags: python

> Write a program that asks the user for a file containing a list of items to be completed and a name for an output file. Your program should then write the list, with item numbers to the output file. For example, if the input file is:

```
Finish my python homework.
Buy milk.
Do laundry.
Update webpage.
```

> Then the output file would be:

```
1.  Finish my python homework.
2.  Buy milk.
3.  Do laundry.
4.  Update webpage.
```

I tried to do this the following way:

```
infileNames=input("what is the file that contain a list of items?")
outfileName=input("what is the file that contain a list of items?")
infile=open(infileName,"r")
outfile=open(outfileName,"w")
data=infile.read()
countnolines=len(open(infileName).readlines())
for p in range(1,countnolines+1):
    print(p,data,file=outfile)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

But my outfile looks like:

```
1 Finish my python homework.
Buy milk.
Do laundry.
Update webpage.
2 Finish my python homework.
Buy milk.
Do laundry.
Update webpage.
3 Finish my python homework.
Buy milk.
Do laundry.

Update webpage.
4 Finish my python homework.
Buy milk.
Do laundry.
Update webpags
```

**strong text**thanks guys for help

Comment: Here you read the whole file: `data=infile.read()`. Here you write the whole file on every iteration of your loop: `print(p,data,file=outfile)`. You want to write just one line on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Joe that's not hardly fair -- unlike the first submission of this problem, THIS ONE is a valid question with reasonable input and output given and a proper description of the issue at hand. Obviously the OP has TRIED to solve the problem and is turning to SO for help.

Comment: Not understand where to make change

Answer (score 5):

#### OLD AND BUSTED:

```
infilenames = input("what is the file that contain a list of items?")
outfileName = input("what is the file that contain a list of items?")
infile = open(infilenames)
outfile = open(outfilename,'w')
data = infile.readlines() # a list of the lines of infile

lineno = 1
for line in data:
    print(lineno,line.strip(),file=outfile)
    lineno += 1

outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

#### NEW HOTNESS:

```
with open(INPUT_FILE) as in_, open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as out:
    for i, line in enumerate(in_, 1):
        out.write("{}. {}\n".format(i,line.strip()))
```

Comment: `enumerate(in_, 1)` would be neater

Comment: i am begginier dont know what enumerate do?

Comment: @thanku `enumerate` produces an `enumerate` object which is an iterable consisting of `tuple`s of the form `(number, data)`. `enumerate("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")` produces `[(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c'), ... (25,'z')]`. It's mostly used to keep track of indexes when you need to know both the data in the list AND the index, but in this case it works out nicely for line numbers as well. As @jonrsharpe just taught me, `enumerate` can be given an optional second parameter for the starting number, but defaults to starting at `0`

Comment: I dislike answers like this, because clearly the OP is new to python, and you have just put a bunch of advanced python idioms into your answer without explanation.  How is that helpful?  The OP can't learn from that.

Comment: @SethMMorton For me, it's like a vocab test in English. How is a programmer supposed to learn about new concepts and approaches if they don't see them? They can't, any more than a student can learn a new word without having seen it. So I use a context manager (or two), `enumerate`, and string formatting, then they ask what that is and I write a lengthy response in the comments. The answer doesn't need to explain what `enumerate` means, but if OP doesn't know, that's exactly what the comments are for.

Comment: @AdamSmith I agree with Seth. You've solved the problem in a way that doesn't at all resemble the author's approach. Better or not, it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Decency I respectfully disagree, but will edit to "fix" his approach.

Comment: @Decency: Wrong. The question is, what is the change needed to be done. Clearly, the answer is *use the right method*. This answer might have lacked an explanation, but it does not take away anything from it being a right answer. Just because a carpenter's a beginner doesn't mean he's allowed to use a screwdriver to drive in a nail.

Comment: @Nanashi The proposed "change" is a complete rewrite. I think it's excellent to suggest better solutions in addition to identifying where the poster has made a mistake- but the latter of the two is more important, to me. Adam's answer as is stands now is great.

Comment: @Decency I understand your point, I just happen to disagree. Borrowing Nanashi's metaphor, I don't show the beginning carpenter to flip the screwdriver around to drive with the heavier handle, I show them a hammer. That said, this is better-discussed on meta.SO

Comment: @AdamSmith The point I was making was less about that you were showing new concepts and rewriting the code (which is fine if that is what is needed), but that you did this *without putting any explanation of what you did*.  Without some paragraph or some inline comments, the answer is unhelpful.  I'm all for showing the OP new stuff.